# Likelihood function of VAR-MGARCH-BEKK model?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, likelihood, garch, vector-autoregression

I am doing my dissertation on the spillover effect between countries' markets and looking to use VAR-MGARCH model to do it. For example how would a change/shock of US market index affect Thailand index.
I have found some idea in here: [Equations for VAR model with GARCH errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229325/equations-for-var-model-with-garch-errors/229331#229331)

However, I am struggling with the log-likelihood function when combining the VAR-MGARCH (I am still not sure which MGARCH model, but highly likely will be BEKK).
How exactly do we define the log likelihood based on the model?
I am looking for a concrete formula and the steps to come up with it. My aim is to use MLE to find the parameters for my model.

One example of the likelihood function that I am looking is as below. This is the likelihood function/conditional density function of VAR-GARCH in mean [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1057521916300461#:~:text=Overall%2C%20the%20results%20indicate%20that,magnitude%20and%20sign%20across%20countries.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1057521916300461#:%7E:text=Overall%2C%20the%20results%20indicate%20that,magnitude%20and%20sign%20across%20countries.):
$f\left(\mathrm{x}_t \mid I_{t-1} ; \theta\right)=(2 \pi)^{-1}\left|H_t\right|^{-1 / 2} \exp \left(-\frac{u_t^{\prime}\left(H_t^{-1}\right) u_t}{2}\right)$

I don't understand how they got this from the model they proposed.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Are you looking for a conceptual explanation or a concrete formula?

Comment: Hi Richard, yes I am looking for a concrete formula and the steps to come up with it. I edited the question for clatification

Comment: To further clarify, I found the Likelihood function/formula for VAR, GARCH separately in many articles, but even so I cannot understand how they get the resulting formula. I do understand that it comes from assuming normal distribution but fail to change the original formula for my own model